# SubscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) + blockingGet() = UI skipped frames

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I wrote a RxJava implementation of a TokenManager for a remote API (that I'm consuming via `Retrofit`).  However I ran into a snag where a method call with `blockingGet()` is resulting in skipped UI frames even though I `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`

Basically, I've included `getToken()` as a parameter in the API `search()` call method.  If the token exists, it will be provided, if not, it will be fetched via the API `token()` call. <-- This is the problem.  When this method gets called, it's resulting in skipped frames in the UI (progressbar freezes momentarily + respective logcat `Choreographer skipped frames!!` message)

Looking for suggestions on how to remedy the skipped frames, or suggestions on how to better implement this code.

ListFetcher (class that calls `TokenManager` `getToken()` )

```
public Single<List<Business>> getList(final String latitude, final String longitude) {
    return api
            .search(
                    tokenManager.getToken(),  // <-- Here's the TokenManager reference
                    AppSettings.SEARCH_TERM,
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    AppSettings.SEARCH_RADIUS,
                    Yelp3Api.SEARCH_LIMIT)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(searchResponse -> {
                if (searchResponse.getBusinesses().size() < searchResponse.getTotal()) {
                    return subsequentSearchCalls(searchResponse, latitude, longitude)
                            .map(businesses -> {
                                List<Business> list = new ArrayList<>();
                                list.addAll(searchResponse.getBusinesses());
                                list.addAll(businesses);
                                return list;
                            });
                } else {
                    return Single.just(searchResponse.getBusinesses());
                }
            });
}
```

TokenManager `getToken()`

```
public synchronized String getToken() {
    final String cachedToken = sharedPrefs.getString(tokenKey, "null");
    if (cachedToken.equals("null")) {
        String tokenString = api
                .token(
                        Yelp3Api.GrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS,
                        BuildConfig.YELPFUSION_CLIENT_ID,
                        BuildConfig.YELPFUSION_CLIENT_SECRET)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnSuccess(this::setSharedPrefToken)
                .map(tokenResponse -> String.format(AUTH_FORMAT, tokenResponse.getAccessToken()))
                .blockingGet();
        return tokenString;
    } else {
        return String.format(AUTH_FORMAT, cachedToken);
    }
}
```

Yelp3Api (Retrofit interface)

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("oauth2/token")
Single<TokenResponse> token(
        @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
        @Field("client_id") String clientId,
        @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret
);

@GET("v3/businesses/search")
Single<SearchResponse> search(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        @Query("term") String term,
        @Query("latitude") String latitude,
        @Query("longitude") String longitude,
        @Query("radius") int radius,
        @Query("limit") int limit
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `getToken()` it is not executed lazily. It executes blocking call on your UI thread.
To fix it, wrap getToken in `Single.fromCallable` and `flatMap` it above `api.search()`

Hope this clears out what is actually happening

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is the correct way to go about executing non-Rx code instead of using `blockingGet()` or `just()`   I also found this vid that was helpful: https://caster.io/lessons/fromcallable-converting-slow-methods-into-an-observable/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-writing this using [okhttp authenticator](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html) to request auth credentials and an [okhttp interceptor](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1164) to add the auth header to outgoing requests.

According to [the internet](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1164#issuecomment-146427332), this seems to be a better implementation.

However I'm accepting @Tuby's answer as it is a more direct resolution to the original question.